# Efficient way to find out who delete my file in subversion

Tags: svn

I use this method to found out which file deleted in long time:

```
$ svn diff  -r 79  svn_folder |diffstat
 xxxxxxxxxxx.ksh   |   61 ------------------------------------------------------
 xxxxxxxxxxx.sh    |   61 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 0 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

I'm trying to found out who delete the xxxxxxxxxxx.ksh. Is there a efficient way? I don't want to use 'svn log -v' to query every revision.

Answer (score 0):

To get the log of a deleted file, use

svn log -r lastrevisionthefileexisted
If you want to resurrect the file and keep its version history, use

svn copy url/of/file@lastrevisionthefileexisted -r lastrevisionthefileexisted path/to/workingcopy/file
If you just want the file content but unversioned (e.g., for a quick inspection), use

svn cat url/of/file@lastrevisionthefileexisted -r latrevisionthefileexisted > file
In any case, DO NOT use 'svn up' to get a deleted file back!

Help link : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Subversion.html

Comment: To what question is this an answer?